# I am not able to go in second while loop 1st one is proper but not going in second

Tags: java, javabeans

> i am not able to go in second 'while loop' 1st one is proper but
> not going in second below is the code

```
public List<Patient> getPatients() {
        System.out.println("fetching patient data getPatients=>");
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(patientList)) {
            
            patientList = HelperUtil.convertPatients(wsService.getAllPatients());
            Iterator<Patient> iterator = patientList.iterator();
            
            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                
                Patient patient = iterator.next();
                List<AddressType> addressList = patient.getAddressList();
                Iterator<AddressType> iterator2 = addressList.iterator();
                System.out.println("above 2 while loop=>");
                while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println("inside 2 while loop=>");
                    AddressType address = iterator2.next();
                System.out.println("fetching address=>"+address.getCity()+" "+"fetching street1 =>"+address.getStreet1());
                }
            }
        
        }
        return patientList;
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked if iterator2 has any items to iterate, in other words, if the addressList collection empty ?

Comment: Print your address list, maybe it's empty

Comment: Do sysout on iterator.hasNext() . It must be returning false

Comment: Try your debugger or `System.out.println(addressList.size());`. And please post a [mre].

Comment: thanks guys you all are right i have done this what u all are said